# Simplest Possible Device to Emulate

Tags: emulation

I'm wondering if someone could recommend an *extremely* simple device that I could emulate as a learning project. I've found a number of guides that focus on emulating the CHIP-8 language, but I want to actually emulate hardware. Something simpler than the NES would be ideal. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a real cpu of around a thousand gates called [Zylin](http://opensource.zylin.com/zpu.htm) that's used when smallness or simplicity is the top of the list. The upside is that there's actually a GCC backend for it.